# Как запускать activity на другом дисплее

Tags: java, android

Я подключил к плате экран, а второй подключен по HDMI. Мне нужно чтобы на один экран выводила одну activity, а ну другой дисплей другую activity; при этом это желательно в одном приложении и одновременно, например как в Самсунге в фолд.
Возможно ли такое?

Comment: Ответ: возможно :)